# is there any utf-8 input method under windows?

Tags: windows, ime

I need this kind of IME on ocassions. For example, i'll need to test some programs which claim they support utf-8.

Comment: I see that you didn't accept, did the answer helped? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is only one type of encoding for storing Unicode code points (characters).
You can easily enter Unicode text in Windows using your keyboard or using any standard IME. To make sure you use Unicode, just use another language that does not use Latin characters and is not your native system language.

When a program claim to support UTF-8 it usually means that it can read or write data in this specific Unicode encoding. To test this kind of a program you will need to write UTF-8 data with another program and give it to the tested program as input. Windows notepad can write UTF-8 files.

With all of the above said, there are certain cases when you will want to input a specific Unicode character in Windows using the keyboard. For this task an Unicode code points Input Method Editor will be very helpful.
You can find what you have asked for at this address: http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm
There are few other ways to directly enter Unicode code points in Windows, see following link from the same site: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm